# tableview in scrollview wont scroll

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a UITableView that is a subview of a scrollview. I can select cells just fine but I cannot scroll. The tableview, when it is showing, covers the scrollview completely. How can I make the tableview scroll?

Answer (score 0):

You most likely need to set the content size of the containing `UIScrollview`.

`[containingScrollView setContentSize:youtTableView.contentSize]`;

You should be able to get the appropriate `contentSize` after you `ViewDidLayoutSubviews` method in your `UIViewController` lifeCycle.